# Using a external jar. No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver

Tags: java, web-services, hibernate, jdbc, jboss

Hy guys,

I'm facing a very "commom" problem with the sql driver. But don´t know how to solve. alredy tried almost all solutions out of there.

**the ambient is:**

-Principal JAR: This contains all the login and DB access via Hibernate

-WebService WAR: This has 2 lines of code and only call the Principal JAR

-Jboss: running the WebService on Jboss AS 7.1

**my problem is:**

After starting the server, when I call it´s method I recive the following error:

```
20:39:20,948 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
20:39:20,949 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=SIPAAM;
```

My JAR also has a test class and if I execute that class ALL works fine. It access the DB and obtain all data withought problems. But when I reference it on my WebService it gives that error.
Also my Persistence xml (is located on the .JAR project)

[image]

---

**Additional info:**

**My WebService code:**

```
@WebMethod
    public List<DadosPreProcessamento> getDadosPreProcessamento()
    {
        DadosPreProcessamentoController dadosPreProcessamentoController = DadosPreProcessamentoController.getInstance();
        return dadosPreProcessamentoController.getLista_dadosPreProcessamento();
    }
```

**My Hibernate Query (JAR internal):**

```
Query listQuery = em.createQuery("select object(c) from "
                    + entityClassName + " as c");
return listQuery.getResultList();
```

The error occurs on the getResultList() method.

---

I have alredy tried to add the sqljdbc4 library on my WS project as you can see on the pic bellow:

[image: WS Libs Config]

[image: WS Deploy config]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

Added the sql jar into:

**~\jboss7\modules\org\hibernate\main**

AND

This line at the bottom of the    tag in module.xml on the "main" folder above.

```
<resource-root path="sqljdbc4.jar"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to also add the sqljdbc.jar file to your classpath. You can verify that the driver is in the jar by clicking on Java Resources in your package explorer and finding the class within the package.

Comment: It is alredy there. If I open my principal .JAR wih the packge Explorer it shows the sqljdbc4 on the folder lib (inside the jar). I have also the sqljdbc4 in lib folder on the WebService project. (alredy tried withought it and nothing changed)

Comment: You need BOTH sqljdbc.jar and sqljdbc4.jar.

Comment: If you look at the download from Microsoft if contains both jar files: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774

Comment: BTW, this is the exact reason I use Maven for my dependencies: http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/maven-fundamentals

Answer (score 0):

Verify the value of field `Class-Path` in the `manifest.mf` file contained inside your JAR library; if it does not declare that it does contain the `sqljdbc.jar`, that dependency will not be accessible from outside the JAR.

You also can do a little experiment: unpack the JAR, remove the `Class-Path` field from manifest and repack; the application will inspect content by force, so it should work.